# Rationalise the denominator and simplify $\frac {3\sqrt 2-4}{3\sqrt2+4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions, radicals, rationalising-denominator

Does someone have an idea how to work $\dfrac {3 \sqrt 2 - 4} {3 \sqrt 2 + 4}$ by rationalising the denominator method and simplifying?

Comment: Hint: Multiply by the conjugate of the denominator: ${3 \sqrt 2 - 4}$

Comment: I tried that but i dont know if the answer is correct or not because the answer i got is **17-√2** is it correct ?

Comment: @wen02 It does not look correct, check the numerator of your expression.

Comment: @EmmadKareem Kareem i think i found the mistake i made the new answer i have is **17-12√2**

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: We are using the fact that $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$ to get rid of surds in the 'bottom'.

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{3\sqrt 2 - 4}{3\sqrt 2 + 4} \cdot \dfrac{3\sqrt 2 - 4}{3\sqrt 2 - 4}=$

> $=\dfrac{18-24\sqrt 2 + 16}{(3\sqrt 2)^2-4^2}=\dfrac{34-24\sqrt 2}{18-16}=\dfrac{2(17-12\sqrt 2)}{2}=$

$=17-12\sqrt 2.$

Answer (score 1):

For problems like this, you need to multiply numerator and denominator by the denominator's conjugate. A conjugate is found by flipping the sign from positive to negative or negative to positive in a binomial. So, the denominator's conjugate in the above's equation is $ 3\sqrt{2} -4 $. Multiplying an irrational binomial by it's conjugate will rationalize it, as seen below:
$$ \frac{3\sqrt{2}-4}{3\sqrt{2}+4}\times \frac{3\sqrt{2}-4}{3\sqrt{2}-4} $$
Multiply out the bottom and top
$$ \frac{9\times2-12\sqrt{2}-12\sqrt{2}+16}{9\times2 -16} $$
$$ = \frac{18-24\sqrt{2}+16}{18 -16} $$
$$ = \frac{34-24\sqrt{2}}{2} $$
$$ = 17-12\sqrt{2}$$